# How to tabulate several vertical arrays in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have used the following "for loop" to generate a series of column vectors

```
for x in time:
   S = dot(M, S)                                                               
   print S
```

Where M is (n x n) matrix and S is (n x 1) matrix. I am therefore trying to find the product of these two matrices.

The result is displayed as:

[image]

I would like the result to be displayed in a table like this.

[image]

The number of column vectors is not limited to 4, rather it is "n".

Comment: You may want to look at `pandas`. It provides a nice looking table. Furthermore, Jupyter notebooks display those tables pretty much like your desired output. There are multiples examples here in SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need each iteration as a new column, I guess you will need to accumulate the results in a 2d array and print at the end. For example:

```
import numpy as np

M = np.random.randn(5,5)
S = np.random.randn(5,1)

for x in range(4):
    S = np.c_[S, np.dot(M, S[:,-1])]

np.set_printoptions(precision=5, linewidth=120)
print S
```

which prints:

```
[[  0.19891  -0.46714   2.09736  -5.01507  14.7212 ]
 [  0.6387    0.81975  -2.25251   6.5098   -8.27462]
 [ -0.44047   0.3941    1.81101  -7.24052  23.07632]
 [ -0.17742   0.88452  -2.80172  10.06426 -21.50157]
 [  0.57601  -0.80838   1.14127   1.15622  -4.11907]]
```